# C# - Return Custom Security Groups from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I currently have the following code which successfully gets all Security Groups from AD and adds them into a Check List box:

```
try
{
    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Reading Security Groups from AD.");
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

    foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
    {
        lstAdGroups.Items.Clear();
        lstAdGroups.Items.Add(found);     
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Unexpected error reading Security Groups from AD: " + ex.Message);
}
```

My issue is that it currently pulls *every* Security Group (where ideally I'd only like to only list custom created security groups (eg, exclude any from the Users or Builtin OU's). I can't see if there are any properties against groups to filter 'custom' from out the box. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrincipalSearcher` can only filter based on attributes that are exposed in properties of the various `Principal` classes. If you're looking for groups, you're limited to filtering based on the properties of the `GroupPrincipal` class.

That issues aside, filtering out objects in certain OUs isn't something you can do in a query at all simply because there is no AD attribute that contains the OU that you're allowed to filter on. So there is two ways you can do this:

1. Do what you're already doing, but in your loop, look at the `DistinguishedName` property of the result. If it's in an OU you don't like, then just `continue;`.
2. You can use [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher) directly (which is what `PrincipalSearcher` uses in the background anyway), and filter by the [`isCriticalSystemObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-iscriticalsystemobject) attribute. That will filter out built-in objects like the `Domain Admins` and `Users` groups, etc.

Here is a simple example using `DirectorySearcher` that just outputs the name of each group:

```cs
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher("(&(objectClass=group)(!isCriticalSystemObject=TRUE))");

using (var results = searcher.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
        Console.WriteLine(result.Properties["cn"][0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointer. After playing around with option 2, this seems to do just what I'm after. A quick test and it seems to now list just the Groups I was after.